# How to pass a any numbers of parameters in ci4 routing?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I trying to find a solution to pass a any number of parameter using route.

As an example, if my route is

```
$routes->get('pages/section/widgets/(:num)/(:num)/(:num)', 'Section::widgets/$1/$2/$3');
```

Here I have to promptly declare number of parameters I am passing i.e. 3.

But if I am not sure about number of parameters, then how can I pass that in ci4?
I went through [documentation](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/routing.html) and tried all the possible placeholders. But it won't work as expected.

For more clarity in Laravel we use -

```
Route::get('/{page?}', 'Frontend\HomeController@inside')->where('page', '.*');
```

So in laravel it accept all the parameter and redirect to it's respective method.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research and going through documentation. I have come up with solution that it is not possible with routing. We can achieve this by in-built library `URI class`. Refer [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html) for more information.

As an example -
If I have url like `http://example.com/test1/test2/test3`. Then in routes we can declare like -

```
$routes->get('/(:any)', 'Home::index');
```

But in controller -

```
$uri = service('uri');
print_r($uri->getSegments());//this will give you all the segments in array.
```

So this will print -

```
Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => test2 [2] => test3 )
```

Thanks.